# Change icon by broadcastreceiver

Tags: android

I've been looking for a way to change an icon in my view by broadcast receiver, but I'm not managing to find a way to do so.

First, I created a receiver:

```
public class BroadcastChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
    NetworkStatus conStatus = new NetworkActivity().getConnectionType(context);     
    String status = "Connection type: " + conStatus.getType().toString() + "  --  Internet: " + conStatus.isConnected();
    Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

it works fine when a network shows up. But now I need to check if there is a connectivity from time to time. To make that, I created a method that will ping my service that is somewhere in the internet each 5 seconds, but I don`t know how, from the broadcast receiver, will I change the icon in my activity. I cant use findViewById. This is my sample code to change and Icon (which is not working):

```
    private void startInternetMonitoring(Context context) {     
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors
            .newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    // Run task every 5 seconds
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        int count = 0;

        public void run() {
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.networkStatusIcon);
            switch (count) {
            case 0:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.connecting_icon);
                count = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.offline_icon);
                count = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.online_icon);
                count = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }, 0, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}
```

any help or tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think a TimerTask is a better use for this case.
From http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html

```
    package com.example.androidtimer;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 CheckBox optSingleShot;
 Button btnStart, btnCancel;
 TextView textCounter;

 Timer timer;
 MyTimerTask myTimerTask;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  optSingleShot = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.singleshot);
  btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
  btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
  textCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);

  btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if(timer != null){
     timer.cancel();
    }

    //re-schedule timer here
    //otherwise, IllegalStateException of
    //"TimerTask is scheduled already" 
    //will be thrown
    timer = new Timer();
    myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();

    if(optSingleShot.isChecked()){
     //singleshot delay 1000 ms
     timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 1000);
    }else{
     //delay 1000ms, repeat in 5000ms
     timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 1000, 5000);
    }
   }});

  btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (timer!=null){
     timer.cancel();
     timer = null;
    }
   }
  });

 }

 class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

  @Override
  public void run() {
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
     new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
   final String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

   runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
     textCounter.setText(strDate);
    }});
  }

 }

}
```

The issue seems to be that you **"cant use findViewById"**.

Perhaps move your broadcastreceiver into your activity and register it there. That way you have access to you activity and views from the receiver when it is called.

Comment: Hello r2DoesInc, thanks for the fast answer, but the problem is that I use templates and have several screens, so, if I leave it in a base template, this same TimerTask will be created several times. This is what concerns me because it happened with my ScheduledExecutorService to

Comment: Sounds like your issue is with the templates, not your code. if your template system is preventing you from writing and executing code correctly, then thats where your issue lies.